# Truly headless web browser (with non-headless abilites)?

Tags: ruby, selenium, phantomjs, watir-webdriver, headless

The challenge I'm tasked with is to run headless (most of the time) but have the ability to launch the current state of the headless browser in the default browser on the machine.

By headless I mean no open browser windows. So I'm running PhantomJS in conjunction with waitr-webdriver.

In the headless state I am completing a multi-page form. At the end of the form I need to be able to launch **that page/session with current state** in my native browser. **How can this be accomplished?**

Imagine this scenario:

```
 #1 open_page (Headless)
    @browser = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs
    @browser.goto "www.somewebsite.com"

 #2 fill in form (Headless)
    field = @browser.text_field(:id => 'field')
    field.set 'somevalue' if field.exists?

 #3 click to next page (Headless)
    button = @browser.button(:id => 'submitButton').click 

 #4 fill in form (Headless)
    field = @browser.text_field(:id => 'field')
    field.set 'somevalue' if field.exists?

 #5 click to next page (Headless)
    button = @browser.button(:id => 'submitButton').click

 #6 results page (Open this page in my native browser)
    @browser.open  # {Pseudo-code}
```

`#6` Is not working. This is where I need your advice/recommendation.

Comment: @BroiSatse In the headless state I am completing a multi-page form. At the end of the form I need to be able to launch **that page/session with current state** in my native browser. **How can this be accomplished?**

Comment: There are also a lot of people who thinks that if they know what they asking for, everyone else will without explaining anything.

Comment: @BroiSatse Which part is unclear? I will edit. Thanks.

Comment: it was unclear (you didn't specify which bit is not working) , it's all clear now and I'm looking for solution.

Comment: @BroiSatse I guess you couldn't find anything ..?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52471/discussion-between-broisatse-and-feed-me-code)

Answer (score -1):

You would need to open a different browesr (@browser2) and then load the URL. Keep in mind this won't have the exact same environment as the headless version.

Comment: Sorry I thought you wanted to remain within your ruby framework to launch a browse. Instead it sounds like you want to run a command like "start http://someurl.com/page.html" from a windows command line. This will launch your web browser, at least on a windows machine.