# How to find out difference behavior between chrome driver and phantomjs

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

When I want to have automated browser function with `selenium-webdriver`, I write at first with `chrome driver` and then make it run with `phantomjs`.

But sometimes the two browsers behave differently and the function fails to run with `phantomjs` while `selenium-webdriver` works fine.

Currently, to find out what is wrong I am struggling in command line. I wonder if there is a way to run `phantomjs` with "head" so that I can see the problem at a glance. Or maybe is there way to make `chrome` behave exactly like `phantomjs`?

I'm aware of some web site are restricted to get information by headless server, I'd give up in that case.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769471/phantomjs-but-not-headless and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593396/truly-headless-web-browser-with-non-headless-abilites

Comment: Basically there is nothing practical you can besides taking a bunch of screenshots and piecing together what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same situation a time ago. In that case I used [this gem](https://github.com/mattheworiordan/capybara-screenshot) to take a screenshot on each capybara failure. It doesn't answer to you what has exactly happened, but at least you can find out if page has required elements and so on.

Comment: Oh, my fault, I forgot to ask - do you use capybara gem at all?

Comment: I'm grateful for your answer, but as you mentioned I don't use `capybara`.